# Rotate a simple polygon in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I follow the code tutorial from [the OpenGL programming book](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/GLStart/Tut4), but it doesn't work. It is showing white rectangle at the top left of my window. Could you please tell me what could be wrong with it?

```
#include<windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
float yRot=0.0;
void Render()
{
  //clear color and depth buffer
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glLoadIdentity();//load identity matrix

  glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-4.0f);//move forward 4 units

  //rotate along the y-axis
  glRotatef(yRot,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

  glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f); //blue color

  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);//begin drawing of polygon
    glVertex3f(-0.5f,0.5f,0.0f);//first vertex
    glVertex3f(0.5f,0.5f,0.0f);//second vertex
    glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);//third vertex
    glVertex3f(0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f);//fourth vertex
    glVertex3f(-0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f);//fifth vertex
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);//sixth vertex
  glEnd();//end drawing of polygon

  yRot+=0.1f;//increment the yRot variable
}
//method the reshape the entire figure.
void reshape(int x, int h){
    glViewport(0,0,x,h);
}
void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.2,0.8);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   glutCreateWindow("simple triangles");
   glutDisplayFunc(Render);
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
   init();

   glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Now you are starting with OpenGL is good advice to learn *modern* OpenGL (version >= 3.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're not calling `glutInit(&argc, argv)` in `main()` before all the other GLUT related calls. Second of all, you're not calling `glutSwapBuffers()` in `Render()`.

Besides that you aren't changing the projection matrix, and thus don't have the same resize function as the one presented in the beginning of the tutorial.

```
void Resize(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1.0f, 1000.0f); 

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Changing those things and your code should work.

Comment: May you at my updated code. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/66965b554d65eeb4c1282bc76b0f0b19

Comment: @Ahmed_mosutafa I don't see any `resize`/`reshape` function at all now. Add it again and it will work.